# Infinite loop in Quick Sort?

Tags: c++

When I run this program, I can reach the stage when I input the numbers, but the code simply stops working after that.

The cursor blinks, but I can't do a thing and neither can I input anything else.
If there is a mistake in the code, point it out or if there is a general mistake, then please enlighten me.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void sort(int *a, int o, int p, int r);
int main()
{

    int a[10],i,o=5,p=0,r=9;
    cout<<"Enter the elments \n";
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
             cin>>a[i];
    }       
    sort(a,o,p,r);
    cout<<"\n The Sorted Array is";
    for(int yy=0; yy<10; yy++)
    {
            cout<<a[yy]<<"\n";
    }
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
void sort(int *a, int o, int p, int r)
{
    int ii=0,kj=10,uu,uv,tmp;
    if(p<r)
    {
        while((ii<10)&&(kj>0)){
            while(ii<=o){
                ii++;
            }
            while(kj>=o){
                kj--;
            }
            if(ii<kj)
            {
                tmp=a[ii];
                a[ii] = a[kj];
                a[kj] = tmp;
            }
        }
        uu=(p+o)/2;
        uv=(r+o)/2;
        sort(a,uu,p,o);
        sort(a,uv,o,r);
    }               
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger say?  Which area is it looping within?  BTW, Fortran style vars are long since deprecated...

Comment: Fortran style vars? Please elaborate?

Comment: Single letter or two letter variables for anything outside of VERY simple index counters in loops is a bad way to code.  At a glance, I cannot tell what ii,kj,uu, or uv stand for.  a,i,o,p,r also hurt my head.  In Fortran77, the variable name determined the variable type, but not anymore.  Also, google "Magic Numbers" when you get a chance and don't do that either.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan being a Haskeller (more and more) I much prefer one-letter names, **provided** they are either self-evident, **or** explained with a comment. One-letter names make code much easier to read, IMHO.

Comment: I am ok with 1 letter vars in very obvious situations such as a for loop i,j combo, or perhaps even x,y,z for 3D space manipulations, but I must disagree that a single letter var, even commented on first creation, is easier to read.  Once a function of any length is created, those comments go out of mental scope quickly - and if you are going to take the time to comment a variable name, why not just use a variable name that needs no comment?

Comment: Yes, what Will said. Its the infinite loop at the comparison of ii and kj.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan it's a balancing act of course. If the function is lengthy, then it's a problem. But then it's a problem in itself (the function being so lengthy that stuff goes out of mental scope, I mean). :)

Comment: I think we can both agree that the vars here fall under the catagory of obtuse, non self-evident, and not explained with comments.  Back to work for me :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan that much is *self-evident*. :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you comparing indices in your sort routine? Shouldn't you be comparing *values* at indices?

What you think this is supposed to do?

```
void sort(int *a, int o, int p, int r)
{                               // call in with o=5, p=0, r=9
    int ii=0,kj=10,uu,uv,tmp;   
    if(p<r)
    {
        while((ii<10)&&(kj>0)){
            while(ii<=o){
                ii++;
            }                  // ii is now 6
            while(kj>=o){
                kj--;
            }                  // kj is now 4
            if(ii<kj)          // NEVER true
            {
                tmp=a[ii];
                a[ii] = a[kj];
                a[kj] = tmp;
            }
        }                      // infinite loop
```

Not less importantly, why are you using the hard-coded value 5 for your pivot value? Why do you call it `o` and not `p` at least? One-letter names for vars are fine **only** if they are either self-evident, **or** explained with a comment.

Comment: I mean, if i write a[ii] instead of the ii and similarly for kj, will it be sufficient?

Comment: What if you enter 10 values of 20..29, and then call your sort, with its hard-coded 5 as pivot? Will it work? I think, not likely. :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan it really wasnt that bad. :)

Comment: @user2133056 ah, OK. you're right this would've get changed as well. sorry. :) will think about it.

Comment: @user2133056 it's no good to hard code the position of your pivot like that. the two areas should meet somewhere according to the values in the array, and you sledge your pivot in there in the middle. It's OK to read it from the middle, but then you should swap it out onto the boundary, and progress from there.

Comment: @user2133056 Notice another problem: you do not update your `o` value. From the way how you make the two recursive calls in the end of `sort`, it should point to the partition boundary. If the pivot is at `o` aftr partitioning, you should use `o+1` in the 2nd call. So basically try to re-code your function, and if you get new problems, ask. :)